# What are curves of $C^\infty$ except for finite points called?

Tags: derivatives

I want to know the phrase for *almost* smooth curve, which means,

For a curve $C:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^2$, there is a partition of domain, $[a=a_0,a_1)\cup[a_1,a_2)\cup\cdots\cup[a_{k-1},a_k=b]$ with $a_i<a_{i+1}$ such that all $C_i$, a restriction of $C$ into $[a_i,a_{i+1})$, are of class $C^\infty$.

Is there any common name for this type of curves? For example:

- Piecewise Smooth Curve
- Almost Smooth Curve
- Right-$C^\infty$ Curve

Comment: I don't know if there is a standard name, but I'd choose the first option with no doubt.

Comment: @Analysis: If you're assuming the left- and right-hand limits of the derivatives exist at each $a_{i}$ (this is not guaranteed by the conditions you've written), then _piecewise-smooth_ is fairly standard.

Comment: Thanks to all of you!